# Why is argument null not asignable to paramenter of type setStateAction in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-typescript

I want to pass empty object as initial state for `isAdmin`, but it's not assignable.

```
const Admin = () => {
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const user = getCurrentUser();
        if (user && user.role === 'admin') {
            setIsAdmin(user);
        } else {
            setIsAdmin(null);
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Use generic useState, e.g useState<Person?>(null)

Comment: Typescript infers the type by the value you provided, which is empty object. You should instead provide a generic type - `useState<Person>()`. Another option is to provide a value which will match the `Person` type, so Typescript would infer the correct type